# Embedded CSS Working -- Linked Stylesheet not

Tags: css, stylesheet

I'm encountering a strange problem.  I was working on converting a PSD to CSS / HTML.  I'm using some PNG-24 as image replacements for logos and such.  While working on the file, the CSS is embedded in the HTML HEAD

I finished working, all images and styles worked great.  I then transferred the CSS into a linked stylesheet.  All of a sudden, the image-replaced PNGs don't work (just don't show up) but ALL the other styling is fine.

If I then copy and paste the CSS from the file, BACK into the HTML and embed it in the HEAD it all works fine again...

anything i'm missing?  Not sure why only 90% of the styling would work in the linked file and more-so, that fact that linking the stylesheet is making only certain rules not work..

Comment: nevermind -- as I wrote this i realized the relative links for the images were bad when i moved the CSS.  It really helps writing it all out like this :)

Answer (score 0):

nevermind -- as I wrote this i realized the relative links for the images were bad when i moved the CSS. It really helps writing it all out like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Firebug to see if the styles for the images are listed?